# Change value and add event listener

Tags: javascript, html

I'm generating some inputs, and adding event listener to each of them, how to increase the value * 2, when I'm focusing on each them ?

Here what I've got:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  this.input.value = random;
  input.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    this.value += random * 2;
  })
}
```

Comment: You've attached some code, what seems to be the problem with it?

Comment: Do you mean `this.value = this.value * 2;` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` of an `input` is always a string. `+` does string concatenation when either of its operands is a string.

So you'll want to parse `value` to use it as a number:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  this.input.value = random;
  input.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    this.value = +this.value + random * 2;
  })
}
```

In that, I'm using `+` to coerce `this.value` to a number. Other options are `parseInt`, `parseFloat`, and `Number`.

However, you've said

> how to increase the value * 2, when I'm focusing on each them

That's not what your code tried to do. Your code tried to **add** `random * 2` to the value. To just double it, double it:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  this.input.value = random;
  input.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    this.value = +this.value * 2;
  })
}
```

There I'm still using `+` for emphasis, but `*` will coerce its operands to number, so `this.value *= 2` would also work.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  this.input.value = random;
  input.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    this.value *= 2;
  })
}
```

> I have tried the above code it's working for me